# Restart SBT Shell in IntelliJ IDEA after SIGINT

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I have a bad habit of pressing `Ctrl+C` when I want to copy an error from the SBT shell. This will kill the shell and I can't figure out how to restart it without exiting and reopening the project. Is there a way to do this? It's quite annoying.

EDIT:

Just to clarify for some of you answering: I am on linux. Running the `2020.1.1` release (Community Edition).

This is what my shell looks like after I kill it with `Ctrl+c`

[image]

There is no panel on the side with a Play/Stop/Etc button.

Comment: Which Intellij version/platform? For me linux/2019.3.1 there's a `Start sbt shell` play-button in the top left of the sbt shell tool window I can press to restart if I kill the shell.

Comment: I'm on `linux/2020.1.1` and I don not have these buttons. That panel is completely missing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There should be `Start sbt shell` button on the left-hand side toolbar of `sbt shell` tool window as indicated by the arrow bellow

[image: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9488405/how-to-write-scala-matcher-for-class]

After pressing it the shell should start and the button turns into `Restart sbt shell`

[image]

If the play button is not visible, then the side toolbar is likely hidden, so click on the three dots on the right of `sbt shell` and select `Show Toolbar`

[image]

Comment: I am on linux. I do not have those icons next to my shell. That panel is missing in my IDE.

Comment: That's it!! Thank you!!! (Side note: mine was a gear not three dots)

Answer (score 1):

I am using 2019.3 version of intellij idea currently. In this you have option :

View > Tool Window > Sbt Shell

and you will see the sbt shell. Also you can find it at the bottom where you can find other options like: Terminal and version control(if enabled)

In the prompt window you can see run button(green arrow something like : |>  ) to get your shell started.

Comment: This does not open a new shell. It only opens the killed one back up. I do not have a prompt.

Comment: You can then use the run button on the prompt and click on it to get sbt shell started.